# Dataframe with empty column in the data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of lists with an header row and then the different value rows.

It could happen that is some cases the last "column" has an empty value for all the rows (if just a row has a value it works fine), but DataFrame is not happy about that as the number of columns differs from the header.

I'm thinking to add a None value to the first list without any value before creating the DF, but I wondering if there is a better way to handle this case?

```
data = [
    ["data1", "data2", "data3"],
    ["value11", "value12"],
    ["value21", "value22"],
    ["value31", "value32"]]

headers = data.pop(0)
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns = headers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ["data1", "data2", "data3"],
    ["value11", "value12"],
    ["value21", "value22"],
    ["value31", "value32"]
]

# create dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# set new column names
# this will use ["data1", "data2", "data3"] as new columns, because they are in the first row
df.columns = df.iloc[0].tolist()

# now that you have the right column names, just jump the first line
df = df.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
df
     data1        data2    data3
0   value11      value12    None
1   value21      value22    None
2   value31      value32    None
```

Is this that you want?

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pd.reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) function to add missing columns. You can possibly do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# To prevent throwing exception.
df.columns = headers[:df.shape[1]]
df = df.reindex(headers,axis=1)
```